# Unable to resolve error on loading Stanford NLP Parser

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I keep getting the same error when using the Stanford NLP parser JAR files.

Code:

```
import java.io.Reader;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;

class TypedDependenciesDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }

}
```

error:

> usage: Relation treebank numberRanges

Is it a bug or is there some way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not do anything, hence it should not give any error.
In my opinion, you are trying to run some stanford jar file and missing command line parameters. Can you explain in details how you are trying to execute the above code.

Answer (score -1):

I have an example of using the Stanford parser programmatically on my google page (in the code section near the bottom):
http://sites.google.com/site/nicoflacco/

This was a pain to set up properly so I made it available so you don't have to suffer as much!